# Change order of short_description on catalog_product_view.xml - Magento2

Tags: magento2

How can I change the order of the "short description"? I would like to place it above the "add to cart" button and not under it, like it is now.

**Here how it is right now:**
[image]

**Here how it should be:**
[image]

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following to your "catalog_product_view.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info"/>
        </body>
    </page>
```

Don't forget to clean your cache.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `move` element in your `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.addtocart" />
```

Comment: Thank you! This and the solution above worked perfect! :))